# Redirect JUST subdomain homepage to root domain

Tags: .htaccess

Basically I want sub.domain.com to redirect to domain.com, but only that url.  For example sub.domain.com/page should still load without redirecting.  How can I do this .htaccess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your .htaccess should look like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work within `.htaccess` placed in the root directory. The empty rule (nothing between `^$`) is interpreted as `/` (the root). Your subpages and subdirectories should remain unaffected. Requires mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://new.domain.com/ [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# subdomain home page to main domain page
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com [L,R=301]
```

This works for me as I wanted to have 301 redirect and to https main domain page. I hope this helps. Thanks..